# Set pyflake AND mypy ignore same line

Tags: python, mypy, pyflakes

I write a module for Salt. By the [documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/#documentation) it adds `__salt__` object into `builtins`. So, **pyflake** warn me that `__salt__` is undefined when I run **prospector** and **mypy** says the same, that `__salt__` is undefined! I can ignore either for **pyflake** with `# noqa: F821` or for **mypy** with `# type: ignore` on that line.

The question is! How to ignore for both of them?

Comment: The code, por favor.

Comment: Try `# type: ignore # noqa` at the end of line?

Comment: Thanks @vahdet it works!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

PEP 484 specifies towards the end of the [section on type comments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-comments) the following:

> In some cases, linting tools or other comments may be needed on the same line as a type comment. In these cases, the type comment should be before other comments and linting markers:
>
> # type: ignore # ~comment or other marker~

So, as Ryan Tam suggested, `# type: ignore # noqa` is the correct way to ignore both.

Comment: hmm... doesn't seem to work with mypy and pylint -- they both want to go first

Comment: @shaunc - seems to work now for me: `# type: ignore # pylint: disable=E1137`

Comment: This worked for me with Pylance and flake8, `# type: ignore # noqa: F821`

Comment: Combine **mypy**, **flake8**, and **pylint** (if order is correct, you need only _two_ `#`): `# type: ignore  # noqa:F401  pylint:disable=unused-import`